# Retrieve name of vendor - WooCommerce & The official product vendors plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using the Product Vendors plugin for WooCommerce (https://woocommerce.com/products/product-vendors/).

I'm also creating a custom loop for a page builder module, which pulls products by ID.

Using the above, I'm able to pull the WC_Product data using:

```
$thisProduct = new WC_product($id);
```

From there, I can get the price/product image etc using

```
$image = $thisProduct->get_image();
$price = $thisProduct->get_price();
```

Does anyone know how I would be able to pull the Vendors name? I've one a var_dump on the full $thisProduct, and it doesn't contain the vendor name anywhere within.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure this out, In order to retrieve the vendor information, we can use the following ($id being the product ID)

```
$sold_by = WC_Product_Vendors_Utils::get_sold_by_link( $id );
```

$sold_by will then contain an array of the vendor info, such as the store name and the link to the vendor store, which we can retrieve such as:

```
$vendor_link = esc_url( $sold_by['link'] );
$vendor_name = $sold_by['name'];
```

Thanks guys, hopefully this can be of assistance with someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If that product is having a vendor mostly it will be saved under 'post_author'; You can retrieve Vendor by that author id.

```
$author         =   get_user_by( 'id', $product->post->post_author );
```

This variable `$author` will have all the info like name.

Comment: Thanks Alice, Unfortunately, the author meta doesn't contain the specific store name. But I've found a solution which I'll post below.